# Getting error after running the jasmine test case :- TypeError: this.snackBarRef.dismiss is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine, istanbul

I am getting an error after running the test case. Below is my ts file.

```js
    import { Component, OnInit, Inject} from '@angular/core';
    import { MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA } from '@angular/material';
    import { MatSnackBarRef } from '@angular/material';

    @Component({
        selector: 'Message',
        templateUrl: './Message.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./Message.component.scss'],
    })
    export class MessageComponent implements OnInit {
        constructor(
            @Inject(MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA) public data: any,
            public snackBarRef: MatSnackBarRef<MessageComponent>
        ) {}

        ngOnInit() {}

        dismiss(): void {
            this.snackBarRef.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

I am getting the following error - TypeError: this.snackBarRef.dismiss is not a function

I have spied on the function as below -

```
describe('MessageComponent', () => {
let component: MessageComponent;
let fixture;

beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [{ provide: MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA, useValue: {} }, { provide: MatSnackBarRef, useValue: {} }],
        declarations: [MessageComponent],
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MessageComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    spyOn(component, 'dismiss').and.callThrough();
});
it('should call dismiss function', () => {
    component.dismiss();
    expect(component.dismiss).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
});
```

I need the solution to fix this error.

Comment: Pls paste TestBed, this error depends on how you mocked provider `snackBarRef`

Comment: @PrzemyslawPietrzak pasted my entire spec file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In test runtime attribute `snackBarRef` in component instance is {} because you declared it in TestBed (`{ provide: MatSnackBarRef, useValue: {} }`.

You're spying on `dismiss` method (in test runtime). Dismiss is calling `this.snackBarRef.dismiss` and because of testBed `this.snackBarRef` is {} so `this.snackBarRef.dismiss` is undefined, and calling it throws error.

To fix that create more complex mock of `snackBarRef` by e.g. `{ provide: MatSnackBarRef, useValue: { dismiss: () => {} } }`. In that case test will not crashed.

Also will be good to spy on `this.snackBarRef.dismiss` and check if was called.

Comment: Glad to help :)